# get woocommerce product variation id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i am currently developing an extension for woocommerce. I am hooking into the admin variations tab like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes' ,'wwp_add_variable_wholesale_price' );

function wwp_add_variable_wholesale_price(){

    global $post, $woocommerce;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    echo $post_id;

}
```

Them above is currently displayin the parent product id, and not the variation id. Does anyone know how to get the actual variation id?

Comment: It seems hard to help without more context.  Do you have more code you can post?  What framework are you using?  How are the database tables structured, if there are any?

Comment: i am using wordpress. No this is all the code i have created. Everything else is generated by wordpress / woocommerce.

Comment: So you're using the posts to store different products, 1 post per product?

Comment: yes that's how woocommerce works. it will then store a variation of that product as a separate post.

Comment: Gotcha.  No experience with woocommerce, best of luck though!

Answer (score 0):

Add the action like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'wwp_add_variable_wholesale_price', 10, 3);

function wwp_add_variable_wholesale_price($loop, $variation_data, $variation){

global $post, $woocommerce;
$post_id = $variation->ID;
echo $post_id;

}
```